# Getting Nokia mobile hanged when form having choicegroup with POPUP style and Three TextField After select POPUP

Tags: java-me, nokia, midp, lcdui

I am developing an J2ME application  having `choicegroup` with `POPUP` style and Three `TextField` . When I was tested my application on Nokia X2-01 device I found following issue regarding `choicegroup POPUP`
Issue :-
When I pressed OK key (Center Key) to open `choicegroup` list items and select something and goes back to the form that has `choicegroup`., left and right soft keys get hanged and no event occurs on pressing these any of the soft key.

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: did you test your code on anything else but this device? emulator, other device? if yes, what were results?

Comment: in other Devices it is working ...but requirement  it Have to Work on Nokia X2-01 Also.....

Comment: I see. In _X2-01_, after you're back in form, does it allow you to scroll to other items in form? so far it looks pretty much like bug in Nokia; one workaround that comes to mind likely to re-code to use implicit list (at dedicated screen) instead of popup choicegroup

Comment: Do you can post an example of code?